# VSTS secrets as environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines

In the VSTS build, I set various variables (Edit build -> Variables tab), some I set as secret (click the lock), some I don't.

In the build, I run a command prompt task to run `set` -- e.g. show me all the environment variables.  Those marked as secret aren't present.

How do I get VSTS secrets into environment variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add secret variable as task environment variable in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037493/how-to-add-secret-variable-as-task-environment-variable-in-vsts)

Comment: And my answer can be found on that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374601/1633949

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Secret variables are:

- Encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key.
- Not returned back to the client. They are automatically masked out of
  any log output from the build or release.
- **Not decrypted into environment variables. So scripts and programs run
  by your build steps are not given access by default.**
- **Decrypted for access by your build steps. So you can use them in
  password arguments and also pass them explicitly into a script or a
  program from your build step (for example as `$(password)`).**

So, Secure variables need to be passed in to tasks as inputs. Check this case: [How to add secret variable as task environment variable in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037493/how-to-add-secret-variable-as-task-environment-variable-in-vsts)

Comment: So my task would need to take `%SECURE%` in as an arg, then within the task `set SECURE=%SECURE%` to re-form it as an env var? (I'm trying to pass secure configs into `dotnet test`. Arguments of mocking these details aside.)

Comment: Is there any way to enumerate them and update VSTS step as the pipeline is being executed? this works okay when you have 1 or 2 variables, but managing 20 becomes ridiculously tedious