# Powershell Access Azure DevOps Secret Variables

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am attempting to read an Azure DevOps secret variable from a Powershell pipeline script. The variable looks like this within Azure:

[image]

I've attempted to access the secret variable both as a `param` such as

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    $SecurePassword = $env:Password
)
```

and simply as an environment variable such as

```
$SecurePassword = $env:Password
```

Unfortunately the variable continues to appear null using either method.

[image]

I have no issue accessing *non-secret* variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---------------------------------------- **EDIT** ----------------------------------------

I found documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables) stating that secrets are available to scripts within the pipeline if explicitly mapped in the environment section of the task.

[image]

I've updated my Powershell task and attempted to map the variable as both `$(Password)` and `Password` without any luck.

[image]

Mapping `$(Password)` as above reveals the string hidden behind asterisks.

[image: Using $(Password) returns]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS secrets as environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110315/vsts-secrets-as-environment-variables)

Comment: It would break security if you could do that - theoretically you could extract a bunch of passwords this way.

Comment: According to the information in your log, you should want to use ConvertTo-SecureString to decrypt encrypted environment variables, but this only applies to strings encrypted with powershell, and Secret variables in azure devops are encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key. They are Automatically masked out of any log output from the build or release. So I think you can't decrypt it in the log.

Comment: I've edited my question to include useful information I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a requirement to create a new project in Azure DevOps and needed to migrate all of the pipelines to the new project.  Lo and behold, no one knew all of the secrets, and export / import doesn't accomplish this.

I wrote a script to output all environment variables into an "Extensions" tab next to the build summary.  It's formatted and everything.

The key to outputting the secret is by altering the string by inserting the '<-eliminate->' phrase within the secret value and saving to a file.  Once the file is created, we then remove all instances of the string '<-eliminate->', save the file, and there it sits as an extension page to the build summary.

I would like to somehow find All secrets dynamically, but for now manually defining the variable name does the trick.

I re-formatted for this post and removed proprietary info, please let me know if it's broken :)

```
function GetSecretLength ($secretVar){
     $i = 0;
     while($true){
          try { 
               $secretVar.substring(0,$i)|out-null 
          } catch { 
               break
          };
          $i++; 
     }
     if ($i -le 1) { return 1 }
     else { return $i-1 };
} 
function GetSecret($secret){
     $length = GetSecretLength($secret);
     if ($length -ge 2) {
        return $secret.substring(0,$length-1 )+"<-eliminate->"+$secret.substring($length-1,1)
    } elseif ($length -eq 1) {
        return $secret+"<-eliminate->"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
} 

$var = (gci env:*).GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name
$out = ""

Foreach ($v in $var) { $out = $out + "`t{0,-28} = {1,-28}`n" -f $v.Name, (GetSecret($v.Value)) }

$fileName = "$env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\build-variables.md"
write-output "dump variables on $fileName"
set-content $fileName $out

write-output "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=Environment Variables;]$fileName"

((Get-Content -path $fileName -Raw) -replace '<-eliminate->', '') | Set-Content -Path $fileName
```

You have to add the secret variables that you want into the "Environment Variables" of the Powershell task:
[image: Environment Variables]

You end up with this pretty tab:
[image]

Comment: You are a bad guy - but that worked :D Thanks! As of now, there is no "Extensions" tab in that case, but a section under the summary.

Comment: @patman This no longer displays secrets, only the unmasked environment variables.

Comment: @Ostrava I guess they caught on to me lol

Comment: @patman - unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just store the password in a keyvault as a secret? then there are azure commands for accessing the secret, and avoid all this. Heck, we generate random passwords, store them in keyvaults, then access the contents in the appropriate resource, without ever needing to expose the decrypted secret in a powershell command, like in an ARM template for an azure sql server database.

I know this doesn't solve your initial question, but it is a workaround that does work.

Comment: Would be great, if you could list the mentioned azure commands for accessing the secrets and/or pass a link to the documentation