# How to pass a secret type variable to script?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I defined some build definition variables, of which some i made as secret type.

I am trying to pass the secret variable `$RPASS` to an inline powershell script task on TFS, but it appears thats not working.

I looked at this post here: [How to add secret variable as task environment variable in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037493/how-to-add-secret-variable-as-task-environment-variable-in-vsts)

however , the examples use command line.

is it possible to pass arguments like that in a powershell inline task?

```
$sec = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
"$RPASS".ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}
$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -args "$env:USER", $sec
Send-MailMessage -From "tfs@domain.com" -Subject "YAY!" -To "user@domain.com" -Body "$env:DB_NAME" -SmtpServer server.com -Port 25 -Credential $creds
```

Following the second answer in that post, i tried passing in the arguments

```
$(RPASS)
```

[image: arg]

and then changed this line `$arg[0].ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}`

but that didnt work either

> [error]Cannot index into a null array.

I tried passing it directly into the script as so:

```
$(RPASS).ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}
```

but that resulted in error:

```
+ ********.ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}
+                                 ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression


2019-06-13T00:57:50.7974750Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ConvertTo-SecureString` in your inline script:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$(RPASS)" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($env:USERNAME, $securePassword)
```

You don't need to pass the argument, because TFS will resolve the variable in the inline script

Comment: So I can eliminate this line? .ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}

Comment: You don't need that anymore. These two lines create the credential object, which can be used with the Send-MailMessage cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it in the arguments but you also need to add a param in the script:

```
Param (
 [string]$RPASS
)
$sec = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$RPASS.ToCharArray()|%{$sec.AppendChar($_)}
```

And in the "Arguments" field pass the variable:

```
-RPASS $(RPASS)
```

[image]

You can see, if I only do `$RPASS.ToCharArray()` I will see the secret variable:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reason I didnt use param is because online script is limited to 500 chars :/

Comment: You can do it in one line with less chars: `Param($RPASS)`